# What are the Acts of Solomon?

Tags: 1-kings, solomon, wisdom-of-solomon

In 1 Kings 11:41, it mentions that all the things Solomon did until he died was written in the acts of Solomon. Is this a non-canonical book? Is this another way of describing Proverbs? Appreciate y'all. God Bless.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know nothing about the various non-canonical books that are referenced in the Bible, and there are many of them.  For example:

- 1 Chron 29:29 - Now the acts of King David, from first to last, are indeed written in **[1]** the Chronicles of Samuel the Seer, **[2]** the Chronicles of Nathan the Prophet, and **[3]** the Chronicles of Gad the Seer,
- 2 Chron 9:29 - As for the rest of the acts of Solomon, from beginning to end, are they not written in **[2]** the Records of Nathan the Prophet, in **[4]** the Prophecy of Ahijah the Shilonite, and in **[5]** the Visions of Iddo the Seer concerning Jeroboam son of Nebat?
- 1 Kings 11:41 - And the rest of **the acts of Solomon**, and all that he did, and his wisdom, are they not written in the book of the acts of Solomon?
- Josh 10:13 - So the sun stood still and the moon stopped until the nation took vengeance upon its enemies. Is this not written in the **Book of Jashar**? “So the sun stopped in the middle of the sky and delayed going down about a full day.”
- 2 Sam 1:18 - and he ordered that the sons of Judah be taught the Song of the Bow. It is written in the **Book of Jashar**

There are many more.